How to change the order of ggsurvplot legends numerically for Kaplan Meier curves?
I made a graph of Kaplan Meier curves for a pesticide bioassay of 4 concentrations (negative control, 1/10000 field rate, 1/100 field rate and field rate), which was recorded in the data frame as 0, 0.0001, 0.01 and 1. I expected the legend and curves in the order from the low concentration to high concentration:
0 (negative control)
0.0001 (1/10000 field rate)
0.01 (1/100 field rate)
1 (field rate)

However, 0.0001 was presented as the scientific number 1e-04 in the ggsurvplot and therefore the legend order was strange:
0 
0.01 
1 
1e-04 

This issue also happened in my other bioassays with a serial dilution of many concentrations because the legend was in order alphabetically instead of numerically.
I want to order the legend of Kaplan Meier curves based on the concentrations of the pesticide.

Factor order is alpha -lexical unless set by the programmer. Many, many prior discussions of this. Do some searching.
